# Group_Concat() is not working properly in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have three tables :
em_employee :

```
emp_number | emp_firstname |
+------------+---------------+
|          1 | Vikram        |
|          2 | S.            |
|          3 | Gopal         |
|          4 | Vaishnavi     |
|          5 | Srinivasan    |
|          6 | Saravanan
```

em_project

```
+------------+------------------------------+
| project_id | name                         |
+------------+------------------------------+
|        339 | MoneyGram                    |
|        340 | SERVICE LINE HEAD COMPLIANCE |
|        341 | SERVICE LINE HEAD ANALYTICS  |
|        342 | GSI                          |
|        343 | Tandem                       |
|        344 | Master Card                  |
+------------+------------------------------+
```

em_project_employee:

```
+------------+------------+
| emp_number | project_id |
+------------+------------+
|          1 |        339 |
|          2 |        340 |
|          3 |        341 |
|          4 |        342 |
|          1 |        343 |
|          6 |        344 |
|          2 |        342 |
+------------+------------+
```

And I want Output like :

```
+------------+----------------------------------+
| emp_number | name                             |
+------------+----------------------------------+
|        1   | MoneyGram , Tandem               |
|        2   | SERVICE LINE HEAD COMPLIANCE,GSI |
|        3   | SERVICE LINE HEAD ANALYTICS      |
|        4   | GSI                              |
|        6   | Master Card                      |
+------------+----------------------------------+
```

I have tried it with GROUP_CONCAT, but something going wrong. Please help me on this.

Comment: Means? I am not getting.

Comment: That means don't include tags that are irrelevant to your question, like `sql-server`.

Comment: *but something going wrong.* Were you going to tell us what's wrong? Or were you hoping we'd guess what you tried and what the problem was.

Comment: Okay okay Got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this query, it produes that output:

```
SELECT emp_number, GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM em_project p 
INNER JOIN em_project_employee em ON p.project_id = em.project_id 
GROUP BY emp_number;
```

The order of the data will e slightly different from what's in your desired output. If the ordering is important.

```
GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY p.project_id)
```